# Javascript to html in VS code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

To learn more about how to code in html, I was seeing if I could recreate Brave Coder's bulk email sender on my own. When I couldn't figure it out, I reviewed the code in his video https://youtu.be/JhQONaHxLko. Although I have edited mine to be nearly identical, I cant seem to link my Javascript to the index.html. I have screenshots below.

The code should add "To email" input boxes when the add more button is pressed. Its not working. I checked to see if the display wasn't working and the extra boxes were behind the others, but it wasn't.

Any ideas?

The links to the app.js is properly sourced. They are in the body section at the bottom. I tried it in the top and in the head and no luck. I'm not very experienced, so I am having a hard time solving it. The tittle of the source for the app.js file is precisely "~/Email/app.js", but yet it doesn't run. It could be something wrong with the js itself, but Ive checked every character and I cannot find a difference between mine and Brave Coder's in the video, yet his works fine. This leads me to think its just not calling the function.

It may also be something wrong with the div class itself, if the button is not properly working. But I'm pretty sure its code is right.

I could be over looking something obvious, I'm just not sure at this point.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Bulk Email Sender</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "wrapper">
        <div class="alert">Test</div>
          <form class="form">
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="text" placeholder="name" class="input"
              required/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="From :(email)"
                  class="input"
                  required/>
            </div>
            <div class="multiple-fields" id="multipleFields">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="To:(email)"
                      class="input"
                      required/>
                    <button type="button" id="addMore" class="my-btn btn-sm">
                      Add More
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Reply-to: (optional)"
                class="input">
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Subject: (First, Last)"
                class="input" required>
            </div>
            <div class ="input-box">
                <textarea class ="input"
                placeholder= "message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="file" placeholder="file"
                class="input">
            </div>
            <button 
              type="submit" 
              class="my-btn"
              style="width: 100%; margin-top: 15px"
            >
              Send Mail
            </button>
          </form>
        </div> 

    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--App.js-->
    <script src="Email/app.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

~/Email/app.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addMore").on("click", function() {
            var html = `<div class="input-box"><input type="email"
        placeholder ="To:(email)" class="input" required /></
        div>`;

            $("#multipleFields").on("click", (html));
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us your folder structure so we can see where each file is ? Thanks !

Comment: `$("#multipleFields").on("click", (html));` doesn’t do anything. `html` isn’t a function, so what is supposed to happen here? Did you mean `$("#multipleFields").append(html);`? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Comment: Check this doc section (https://api.jquery.com/append/), u maybe want to append some child

Comment: I checked the video. `$("#multipleFields").on("click", (html));` doesn’t exist there; it says `$("#multipleFields").append(html);`. Consider _not_ learning from videos, but from the official documentation and tutorials instead. [JS docs](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), [JS tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide), [jQuery API](//api.jquery.com), [jQuery Learning Center](//learn.jquery.com). And learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I realized I miss pasted my code. It should have been .append(html); rather than .on(html); even so, It wasn’t running properly with the append, which was why I was playing around with it. But Ive rewritten it to work properly now. Also, thank you for the suggestion to not solely rely on YouTube. Thank you for the links Sebastian, they will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed some issues with the JS within your app.JS file.  That was the main adjustment I made to get it working again.

I would just advise using CSV or semi-colon for multiple emails.  Much easier to work with on the back-end and in the database.

`test@email.com;test2@email.com;test3@email.com`

`test@email.com,test2@email.com,test3@email.com`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let emailCounter = 0;
  $("#addMore").click(() => {
    var html = `<div class="input-box"><input name="email${emailCounter++}type="email"
        placeholder ="To:(email)" class="input" required /></
        div>`;

    $("#toEmails").append(html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!--CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Bulk Email Sender</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="alert">Test</div>
    <form class="form">
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" class="input" required />
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="email" placeholder="From :(email)" class="input" required />
      </div>
      <div class="multiple-fields" id="multipleFields">
        <div id="toEmails">
          <div class="input-box">
            <input type="email" placeholder="To:(email)" class="input" required />
            <button type="button" id="addMore" class="my-btn btn-sm">
                            Add More
                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject: (First, Last)" class="input" required />
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <textarea class="input" placeholder="message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="file" placeholder="file" class="input" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="my-btn" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 15px">
                Send Mail
            </button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!--App.js
    <script src="Email/app.js"></script>
    -->
</body>
```